# Gradient of composition $\nabla(f\circ \mathbf A)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Chain_rule) lists the identity for the gradient of a composition as $$\nabla(f\circ \mathbf A) = (\nabla f\circ \mathbf A)\nabla \mathbf A$$

First, is this formula correct?

Assuming it is:

Second, what does $\nabla\mathbf A$ mean?  Is it the Jacobian of $\mathbf A$?

And finally, what does it mean to multiply the vector $\nabla f\circ \mathbf A$ and the matrix $\nabla \mathbf A$?  Is it some type of tensor product?  That doesn't seem like it would result in the correct type of object.  Or is $\nabla f\circ \mathbf A$ supposed to be a row matrix and then you just use matrix multiplication?

Comment: The formula is correct with $\nabla A$ the Jacobian matrix. It's the usual product of matrices. $\nabla f(A(x))$ is a $1\times n$ matrix, while $\nabla A(x)$ is a a $n\times s$ matrix, resulting in a $1\times s$ matrix.

Comment: OK, cool.  Thanks.

Comment: This is simply the chain rule stated in terms of $\nabla$ operator.