# How can I solve the gradient here?

Tags: vector-analysis, gradient-flows

My teacher taught us what is the gradient of a function and what it means. But in this equation: df = ∇f dl , I dont know how to solve ∇f. 
[My teacher put this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDplF.jpg)

Can anyone please teach me how to solve step by step that equation? I tried but I dont get to the same result. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: This is the equation--> $df=∇f\:dl$

Comment: @user71209 Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have to solve anything it’s simply the differential of $f$expressed by a dot product of the gradient and $d\vec l$, thus

$$df =\nabla f \cdot d\vec l=f_x dx+f_ydy+f_zdz$$

Comment: No, I mean, imagine you want to calculate the gradient operator in different systems (cartesian,cylindrical,spherical). And let's say that "df" and "dl" are known values and you have to solve "∇f" for seeing what  its look like in different coordinates systems. How can you solve that gradient?

Comment: Solve a system of d linear equations corresponding to different directional derivatives, where d is the dimension. Just one DF and do will not be enough except in one dimension.

Comment: @user71209 You can obtain the expression for other coordinates system by chain rule, see this example here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971674/missing-1-r-factor-in-gradient-of-polar-function

Comment: I see it much harder that it really is. There is not another simple way to solve it? I mean like a equation, nor matrix nor chain rule

Comment: @user71209 I don't know any shortcut for it